# Can not communicate sparkun OBDII UART with Raspberry pi 4 over (minicom)

Tags: raspberry-pi, uart, obd-ii, sparkfun

I'm trying to use Sparkfun's [OBD-II-UART board](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9555) to interface with a CAN network using a Raspberry pi 4. Upon connecting to sudo screen /dev/ttyAMA0 and when I send the commands, I'm not able to get any response from the OBD-II-UART board. Can anyone suggest why it is not communicating?

Comment: Are you sure you have configured the right baud rate? Are you sure you're sending the right commands? What kind of devices are also on the CAN-bus?